# Why doesn't C store strings as a linked list of characters?

Tags: c, string, data-structures, linked-list

In C strings are stored as an array of character eliminated with '\0'. So I can do this:

```
char string[] = "Hello, World!";
```

or

```
char* string = "Hello, World!";
```

I can just use predefined string functions [`strcpy()`] to overcome the fact that I cannot exceed the initialized length of the string.

I am trying to make a program that does basic math operations on very large numbers. I thought of storing these digits in a linked list. But perhaps I can just store them in a string (char*) and make functions to operate directly on that.

What benefit will I have of using linked lists in the above program?

Comment: This question is too unfocused: either ask about C strings or about representing arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: The only benefit I can think of is that you can easily remove a digit without the need to shift the rest. Any other operation is more expensive.

Comment: keeping numbers in c-strings makes printing much easier

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the question... hmm

Comment: One reason that C does not store strings as linked lists of characters is that such a representation would be much larger than the array representation that actually is used, and it would be very inefficient to to process.

Comment: linked lists are very slow. c is a systems language

Comment: *I can just use predefined string functions [`strcpy()`] to overcome the fact that I cannot exceed the initialized length of the string.* If you're using `strcpy` to copy more into a string than it's defined to hold, if you're assuming from the fact that you're not getting an error message, or that it "seems" to be working, that somehow, `strcpy` is automatically allocating memory for your larger string — then I'm afraid you have some very wrong ideas about string allocation in C.

Comment: If you're trying to implement code to manipulate large numbers, then thinking of them as "strings" is not a bad way to start.  They probably won't be arrays of `char` (let along digit characters `'0'` to `'9'`), and they probably won't be null-terminated, but they will certainly be variable-length arrays, growing to be however big they need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C language is defined in standards like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or etter.

For historical reasons, strings in C are represented in contiguous memory.

And in 2021, most processors (x86-64, ARM, PowerPC ....) are efficiently handling them (with an optimizing compiler, like a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/))

Of course, you can develop your C library representing your "string" like type as linked lists. Look into [Glib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/) (part of GTK), and study its source code for inspiration.

UTF8 encoding has several bytes (`char`) per characters (like `é` or  `€`)

Some implementations of Prolog represented strings as linked lists.

Comment: For very large strings, however, it is worth some overhead for more advanced memory management. I recommend Googling around “ropes” and “skip lists”.

Comment: I believe that Glib implement these. I know about ropes and skip lists, but never used them in practice.